# What does "down in the dumps" means?

Tags: meaning

What does "**I am often down in the dumps**" mean?

Is it "*to feel bad about messed up things*"?

Comment: I don't understand where you get the part "aboud messed up things". It just mean unhappy, feeling sad and unhappy https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/down-in-the-dumps You need to add the reasons or causes to the phrase, they are not implicitly stated.

Comment: This question can be answered by simply searching for "meaning down in the dumps", etc. If you do that, and still have questions, then you can edit your question to tell us what you found and what you don't understand. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Being "**down in the dumps**" means to be "In a gloomy or depressed mood". ([Source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/down-in-the-dumps))

For example: "She's been down in the dumps ever since she lost the match."